# restart fragment from another activity/fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm new in adroid, so i have a trivial problem, but i don't know how to solve it. In android studio i created default swipe tabs with fragments (it looks like that http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/ ). I have 2 fragments ("Setup" and "Histrory"). In Histrory fragment i wrote all logic (i created list (with custom adapter which return row view with custom design) and fill it with data from sql ). In my Setup fragment i have alertDialog which adding some data to sql and History fragment generate list based on this data (from sql).

My problem is: I don't know how to update Histrory Fragment from Setup fragment. My adapter require a View which i can't(i don't know how) get from Setup Fragment. It looks like i should rebuild/restart History fragment and it will run onCreateView with my function and i will get latest(updated) list? Or i need to get view from History Fragment in Setup Fragment and run update function from Setup fragment passing view to UpdateHistoryList? I spend all day on this problem and couldn't find any good and simple solution...

**HistoryFragment.java**

```
  public class HistoryFragment extends Fragment {


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.historyfragment, container, false);

        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////
        UpdateHistoryList(rootView); ////// This work fine.
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////

        return rootView;
    }

    // This function make request to db and fill array with some values
    public void UpdateHistoryList(View v) {

        <Some code>

        generateHistoryList(v, myarray);

    }

    public void generateHistoryList(View v,String[] myarray) {

        history_adapter adapter = new history_adapter(v.getContext(), values);
        ListView listView = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.history_list);

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

}
```

**history_adapter.java**

```
// generate row look
public class history_adapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
   private final Context context;
   private final String[] myarray;


   public history_adapter(Context context, String[] myarray) {
       super(context, R.layout.history_row, values);
       this.context = context;
       this.myarray = myarray;

   }

   @Override
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)   context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
       View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.history_row, parent, false);

       TextView catName = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.catName);

       catName.setText(myarray[position]);

       return rowView;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: you need to share data between fragments? if that is what you wanna do.. you have to do it in your fragmentactivity

Comment: check this tutorial http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Comment: So I need share rootView from HistoryFragment to fragmentactivity and then in SetupActivity get rootView from fragmentactivity and run  update function with this argument?

Comment: You actually don't need a view. Just init listView in onCreate...and instead of v.getContext() call getActivity(); Besides, a fragment has the getView() method, which returns the view vom onCreateView(). To get information from one fragment to the other, use Listeners...

Comment: ElDuderino, thanks. But i need to call method from other activity, not to share data between fragments. Or i'm wrong

Comment: What I meant is to move this method to your activity and call it from both fragments.